# Page Request not loading fully

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a problem with the request. When I get the page is not getting one particulary data that I need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import requests

def getHTML(url):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True, timeout=None)
    #print r.headers
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def main():
    source = getHTML('http://connected2.me')
    for link in source.find_all('ul'):
        print(link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The data I need to get form the source is in this list

```
<ul class="usersOnlineList clear"></ul>
```

but the result it is always this

```
<ul class="usersOnlineList clear">
</ul>
<ul>
<li><input class="inptIcn icnUser" data-validate="validate(required, username, minlength(3), maxlength(25))" id="fos_user_registration_form_username" maxlength="255" name="fos_user_registration_form[username]" pattern=".{3,255}" placeholder="username" required="required" type="text" value=""/></li>
<li><input class="inptIcn icnPass" data-validate="validate(required, minlength(6))" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword]" placeholder="password" required="required" type="password" value=""/></li>
<li><input class="inptIcn icnEmail" data-validate="validate(required, email)" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" maxlength="255" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" pattern=".{2,255}" placeholder="email" required="required" type="email" value=""/></li>
<li class="formActions"><input class="btn btnGreen" id="signup-btn" name="signup-btn" type="submit" value="Sign Up!"/></li>
</ul>
```

The list is null. Why I can't get the list items only from that list?

Comment: Did You try printing the text? `print link.text`

Comment: It doesn't matter, the data it doesn't exist in the document. That data is loaded dynamic, on fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `<ul class="usersOnlineList clear"></ul>` content is `JavaScript` injected. You have to wait for this to be inserted and `requests` are not able to do this. `selenium` can be a solution for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

def main():
    driver.get("http://connected2.me")
    source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    for link in source.find_all('ul', {'class': 'usersOnlineList'}):
        print(link)

    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're method works like charm, thanks! Is there a method to not open my browser, I mean hidden?